# angularjs directive button click

Tags: angularjs

So i have been fiddling with angularjs directives for a bit. What I am trying to accomplish here, is just triggering the data gets pulled on a button click. How do i go about this process.

```js
formApp.directive('task', function($http) {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.template = "<div><button>Like</button></div>;
    directive.link = function($scope, element) {
        $scope.loadTaskList = function() {
            $http.get(domain + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('stuff')/items?", {
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                }
            }).then(function(resp) {
                if (resp.data.d.results.length > 0) {
                    });
                    console.log(resp.data.d.results);
                }
            });
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="formApp">
<task></task>
</div>
```

Comment: But does it work? Can you please explain a bit more whats going on here

Comment: If you want the button to trigger the loadTaskList function you have to add a ng-click to it. <button ng-click="loadTaskList()"></button>

Comment: ok but why does the <div><button>like</button></div> not display in the UI. It is a template

Comment: You should create a plunker/jsfiddle/codepen/etc. Or, at least, fix the errors in your snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a large number of syntax, as well as logical errors in your directive.

1. `domain` variable is never declared or defined.
2. `formApp` variable is never declared or defined.
3. Directive definition is missing several closing braces.
4. No closing quotes on template string.
5. Closing `});` in strange place in scope method.

Simply fixing all the syntax errors will result in your button appearing. Can't help you with the domain variable problem. I have no idea what that is supposed to be.

```js
    var formApp = angular.module('formApp', []);
    formApp.directive('task', function($http) {
      var directive = {};
      directive.restrict = 'E';
      directive.template = '<div><button ng-click="loadTaskList()">Like</button></div>';
      directive.link = function($scope, element) {
        $scope.loadTaskList = function() {
            $http.get(domain + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('stuff')/items?", {
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
                }
            }).then(function(resp) {
                if (resp.data.d.results.length > 0) {
                    
                    console.log(resp.data.d.results);
                }
            });
        };
     };
     return directive;
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="formApp">
<task></task>
</div>
```